# PHP Won't Match String - Encoding Issue?

Tags: php, string-matching, var-dump, filter-var

**I "solved" this myself: the text files must be encoded ANSI. But I don't know why, or why `filter_var()` didn't help, so I thought this would still be educational for myself and others.**

I haven't learned databases yet so I've started my foray into templates / generated content for my photo gallery pulling info from txt files. I have `categories.txt`:

```
Architectural
Fashion
// etc
```

Then, within my template:

```
$Categories = file('shared/categories.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$This_Page = filter_var($Categories[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$Image_List = file('shared/'.$This_Page.'.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($Categories as $c) {
    if ($c == $This_Page) {
        echo 'test successful!';
    }
    else {
        echo 'test failed';
    }
}
```

This always works. However, if on line 2 I use `Categories[0]`:

If `categories.txt` is encoded UTF-8, `shared/$This_Page.txt` can't be found and the `if` returns "test failed", and `var_dump()` finds `$This_Page` to be 3 characters longer than it should be. Even with `filter_var()`.

Worse, if `categories.txt` is encoded Unicode, the code fails from the very first line with "file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path."

And only if `categories.txt` is encoded ANSI does it work correctly.

Comment: You said you solved the problem but I don't see your solution!

Comment: Sorry, I just rewrote the grammar a little to make it more clear. The solution is just that the text files have to be encoded ANSI.

Comment: I read that file() does not support unicode reading, standard approach could be read file line by line and use `iconv()` or  `mb_convert_encoding()` to convert the content.  If you have a solution to your problem, you can post an answer at bottom.